# Select records which is unique

Tags: mysql

I've a MySql table which contains rows like,

| pid | country |
| --- | --- |
| 436 | 1 |
| 436 | 5 |
| 436 | 7 |
| 439 | 7 |
| 440 | 3 |
| 446 | 7 |
| 446 | 1 |

For Example, I am trying to retrieve products which has only country 7 and should not present in other combination. How can I achieve this?

I tried like below:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE country = 7;
```

but outcome/result contains pid 436,439 and 336. It should only give 439.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *not exists* for this:

```
select *
from table_name t 
where t.country = 7
and not exists (
  select * from table_name t2
  where t2.pid = t.pid and t2.pid != t.pid
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT pid
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY pid
HAVING SUM(country <> 7) = 0;
```